# api express app in Heroku enviroment does not pickup Config Vars

Tags: node.js, typescript, api, express, heroku

I have an API app (Typescript, express, Node js) in the Heroku environment. I have a .env file on the local pc to run the app locally, but in Heroku, I am using Config Vars on Dashboard (also tried to add by Heroku CLI), but both ways did not work
heroku logs --tail shows the problem:

```
021-03-18T23:59:07.087439+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-18T23:59:07.087488+00:00 app[web.1]: > botmanager-api@0.1.0 start /app
2021-03-18T23:59:07.091777+00:00 app[web.1]: > node dist/index.js
2021-03-18T23:59:07.091779+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-18T23:59:09.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-03-18T23:59:09.445138+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/dist/environment.js:11
2021-03-18T23:59:09.445161+00:00 app[web.1]: throw result.error;
2021-03-18T23:59:09.445162+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-03-18T23:59:09.445162+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-18T23:59:09.445167+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/.env'
2021-03-18T23:59:09.445167+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.openSync (fs.js:476:3)
2021-03-18T23:59:09.445168+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:377:35)
2021-03-18T23:59:09.445169+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.config (/app/node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js:96:29)
2021-03-18T23:59:09.445170+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/dist/environment.js:9:33)
2021-03-18T23:59:09.445170+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
2021-03-18T23:59:09.445170+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
2021-03-18T23:59:09.445170+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
2021-03-18T23:59:09.445171+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
2021-03-18T23:59:09.445171+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
2021-03-18T23:59:09.445171+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
2021-03-18T23:59:09.445172+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/dist/database/index.js:17:23)
2021-03-18T23:59:09.445172+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
2021-03-18T23:59:09.445172+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
2021-03-18T23:59:09.445173+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
2021-03-18T23:59:09.445173+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
2021-03-18T23:59:09.445174+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19) {
2021-03-18T23:59:09.445174+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -2,
2021-03-18T23:59:09.445174+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'open',
2021-03-18T23:59:09.445175+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ENOENT',
2021-03-18T23:59:09.445175+00:00 app[web.1]: path: '/app/.env'
2021-03-18T23:59:09.445175+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-03-18T23:59:09.493019+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-03-18T23:59:09.493712+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-03-18T23:59:09.519770+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! botmanager-api@0.1.0 start: `node dist/index.js`
2021-03-18T23:59:09.520055+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-03-18T23:59:09.520423+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-03-18T23:59:09.520749+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the botmanager-api@0.1.0 start script.
2021-03-18T23:59:09.521163+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-03-18T23:59:09.547826+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-18T23:59:09.548363+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-03-18T23:59:09.548700+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-03-18T23_59_09_522Z-debug.log
2021-03-18T23:59:09.611755+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-03-18T23:59:09.733403+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Where and what I am missing.
Thanks

environment.js

```
"use strict";
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.environment = void 0;
const dotenv_1 = __importDefault(require("dotenv"));
const DEFAULT_PORT = 8081;
const result = dotenv_1.default.config();
if (result.error) {
    throw result.error;
}
const { parsed: envs } = result;
console.log(envs);
exports.environment = {
    port: process.env.PORT || DEFAULT_PORT,
    mongoDb: process.env.MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING,
};
//# sourceMappingURL=environment.js.map
```

environment.ts

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

const DEFAULT_PORT = 8081;

const result = dotenv.config();
if (result.error) {
  throw result.error;
}

const { parsed: envs } = result;
console.log(envs);

interface Environment {
  port: number | string;
  mongoDb: string;
}

export const environment: Environment = {
  port: process.env.PORT || DEFAULT_PORT,
  mongoDb: process.env.MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING as string,
};
```

Comment: Is your `.env` file checked into Git?

Comment: no, I don't want to expose vars in GitHub

Comment: What is inside `environment.js`

Comment: updated with environment.ts and environment.js

Comment: What have you tried on the CLI? Heroku uses Git to deploy your app, so if `.env` is not checked into Git your environment variables won't be configured

Comment: the .env file has sensitive info and I don't want to / I don't need to add it into Git repo. I tried heroku config:set KEY_NAME=<value> and also from Desctop add Config Vars - non is working https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars